# EC2, 16.04, Systemd, Supervisord, & Python

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-ec2, supervisord, systemd, ubuntu-16.04

I have a *service* written in **python 2.7** and managed by **supervisord** on an **Ubuntu 16.04 EC2 spot instance**.

On system startup I have a number of **systemd** tasks that need to take place and finish prior to **supervisord** starting the *service*.

When the instance is about to shutdown, I need **supervisord** to capture the event and tell the *service* to gracefully halt. The service will need to stop processing and return any workloads to the queue prior to exiting gracefully.

1. What would be the optimal way to manage system startup in this scenario?
2. What would be the optimal way to manage system shutdown in this scenario?
3. How do I best handle the interaction between **supervisord** and the *service*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we need to install a **systemd task** that we want to run prior to supervisor starting up. Let's create a script, `/usr/bin/pre-supervisor.sh`, that will handle performing that work for us and create the `/lib/systemd/system/pre-supervisor.service` for **systemd.**

```
[Unit]
Description=Task to run prior to supervisor Starting up
After=cloud-init.service
Before=supervisor.service
Requires=cloud-init.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
WorkingDirectory=/usr/bin
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pre-supervisor.sh
RemainAfterExit=no
TimeoutSec=90
User=ubuntu

# Output needs to appear in instance console output
StandardOutput=journal+console

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As you can see, this will run after the ec2 *cloud-init.service* completes, and prior to the *supervisor.service*.

Next, let us modify the `/lib/systemd/system/supervisor.service` to run After the *pres-supervisor.service* completes, instead of after *network.target*.

```
[Unit]
Description=Supervisor process control system for UNIX
Documentation=http://supervisord.org
After=pre-supervisor.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
ExecStop=/usr/bin/supervisorctl $OPTIONS shutdown
ExecReload=/usr/bin/supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf $OPTIONS reload
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=50s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

That will ensure that our *pre-supervisor* tasks run prior to supervisor starting up.

Because these are spot instances, AWS has exposed the termination notice in the meta-data url, I simply need to inject something like:

```
if requests.get("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/spot/termination-time").status_code == 200
```

into my python service, have it check every five seconds or so, and gracefully shutdown as soon as the termination notice appears.